# Ganesha naam japa / mantra for sankalpa?

Tags: ganesha

I have a question in my mind and I am planning to do a 10 day sankalpa meditation on Lord Ganesha to remove obstacles from my mind.
Please recommend a simple naam japa or a basic mantra.
I am hesitating on "Gam Ganapatya namah", because it contains beej mantra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> स्तोत्रं तस्य प्रवक्ष्यामि नामद्वादशकं शुभं।
> **ॐ नमो गणपतये** मंत्र एष उदाहृतः २८।
> **गणपतिर्विघ्नराजो लंबतुंडो गजाननः। द्वैमातुरश्च हेरम्ब एकदंतो गणाधिपः २९। विनायकश्चारुकर्णः पशुपालो भवात्मजः।** द्वादशैतानि नामानि
> प्रातरुत्थाय यः पठेत् ३०। विश्वं तस्य भवेद्वश्यं न च विघ्नं
> भवेत्क्वचित्। महाप्रेताश्शमं यांति पीड्यते व्याधिभिर्न च।
> सर्वपापाद्विनिर्मुक्तो ह्यक्षयं स्वर्गमश्नुते ३१।
>
> I shall tell you the hymn containing his twelve names (in honour) of
> him. **The mantra is: “Om, Namo Gaṇapataye.”**
> **He, who, after getting up in the morning recites these twelve names of him, viz. Gaṇapati, Vighnarāja, Lambatuṇḍa, Gajānana, Dvaimatura,
> Heramba, Ekadanta, Gaṇādhipa, Vināyaka, Cārukarṇa, Paśupāla (and)
> Bhavātmaja”**, would have the entire universe under his control and
> would never meet with any difficulty. Great evil spirits become calm;
> he is not troubled by diseases; being free from all sins, he eternally
> obtains (i.e. lives in) heaven.

**~ [Padma Purana, Srishti Khanda, Chapter 63](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364186.html)**

If you are not comfortable with Mantras owing to Pranava or bijaksharas, You can Just chant the names as provided in this chapter of the Padmapurana

Comment: thank you, this is great